# Need a fix for google sites vertical scroll bar on mobile version of my website when embeding

Tags: html, css, https, embed, google-sites

I am not a professional coder AT ALL, but I've been attempting it on my Google Sites web page recently and have had some success. There is one issue that's really holding me back though: When I embed html code there is always a vertical scroll bar that is distracting and really skews the overall flow of the website. It is a common issue with Google Sites, but I know there has to be a fix because I've seen it done before, I just can't figure it out myself. This is the html language I can provide as an example:

```
<center>
<a href="https://www.pintosporch.com/about-us"
style="color:white; font-size: 25px; scrolling="no"; overflow:hidden;">Meet the Pinto's ></a>
</center>
```

Any help with this will be a literal lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

```
<center style="overflow:hidden;">
<a href="https://www.pintosporch.com/about-us"
style="color:white; font-size: 25px; scrolling='no'; overflow:hidden;">Meet the Pinto's ></a>
</center>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I can't say I've ever used Google Sites before but I can give some advice on what I like to do with my projects to preempt weird vertical bars like that.

Setting some normalizing `css` is really helpful:

```css
#Example

html,
body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   height: 100vh;
   min-height: 100vh;  // for extra vigilance because some browsers are finicky
}
```

The above example removes the default style the browser applies to the page body and ensures the height of the page will at minimum fit to the browser viewport (if no actual body content extends past it).